# Twitter share android

Tags: android, twitter, webview

I followed some tutorials and implemented twitter share for android, I am able to get the Twitter auth URL opened in the webview in dialog.
However, after giving valid credentials and password, tapping on the "Authenticate" button has no action. The same happens with the "No thanks" button, too..

I am facing this issue in Samsung/Moto devices while able to smoothly proceed with HTC. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you testing on which API?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use on these devices?

I had difficulties with open-auth procedures when using Opera Mobile.

You need a browser which is able to tell the system, which Internet page has just been called. (An Intent has to be sent on each click of a link, so that other programs in your system can check, if this link is better to be opened by them instead of the browser).
I know that my Samsung Galaxy SII stock browser is doing it right.

EDIT:
I assume, as you tagged your post with `webview`, that you don't use any browser in a term as I mean it.
Anyway, I'll keep this post for other people which might try it via the browser.

[Voting down myself in my mind]